# Javascript subtracting pixels from percentage

Tags: javascript, web, styling, css

I am looking to use JavaScript to restyle a div on button click. I have everything working, except one thing. One of the things that I want to do is change the maximum height of the div from what I currently have it set to, to 100% - 12px. I tried using the CSS calc() function, but it didn't work. The strangest thing about this is that when I checked the developer console for errors, it did not throw an error. Does anyone know how to do what I am asking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `document.getElementById('myID').outerWidth - 12`

Comment: Try prefixing `calc()`

Comment: I want to use this to alter the maximum height of the element, is that what that does @adeneo?

Comment: is it initially set to 100% ?

Comment: @ParthikGosar The max-height is initially set to 150px, and I want to change it to 100%-12px. It may be helpful to know that even when I try to set a mac-height pixel value in the JavaScript just as an experiment, it does not take effect. Could the CSS that I wrote for it be interfering with it? Some of the CSS was written by me, and some of it wasn't, and that which wasn't uses '!important'.

Comment: Please note that !important has the highest precedence which overrides all other css. Even INLINE styles are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this problem using jQuery by adding a click binding to your button and then getting the height of .parent(). I've demonstrated this in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TGyYv/.

The key is this code.

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    parent_height = $(this).parent().height()
    $(this).height(parent_height - 12)
})
```

When the button is clicked, it gets the parent's height, then sets the button's height to the parent's minus 12!

Comment: Can I do this using getElementById instead? @abeisgreat

Comment: Potentially yes, but things like .parent() or .height() will not work without jQuery. I don't know off the top of my head how to achieve this exact behavior in pure JS, but it is possible.